# RewriteRule - css is missing if I add last slash inside url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want `example.com/video/` - with or without last slash - to be interpreted as `example.com/video.php` - and this works

`example.com/video/5/lorem-ipsum/` - with or without last slash - should be interpreted as `example.com/video.php?id=5&s=lorem-ipsum`

it works only without last `/`
with that slash - the content is there but css is missing

please help

```
<base href='../../'>

RewriteRule ^video/?$ video.php [L]
RewriteRule ^video/([^/]*)/(.*)/?$ video.php?id=$1&s=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following htaccess rules file. Please make sure that your .htaccess file is residing along with your video.php file. Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(video)/(\d+)/([^/]*)/?$ $1.php?id=$2&s=$3 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(video)/?$ $1.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

***JS/CS rewrite/redirect:***
You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: I made all my links absolute and remove `base href` and tried your code. Result - `404 - not found` Cache is cleared and `.htaccess` is on same level as all `.php` files

Comment: @provance, ok so I would like to ask you 2 questions now. 1st- What is the value of your %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}? and 2nd: what is complete path of your .htaccess file? Kindly do let me know on same.

Comment: the path is `https://example.com/.htaccess`. This is also the path of all my php, js and css files. Can't understand your first question - how can I check what is the value of that param ?

Comment: @provance, For `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` in httpd.conf file its value will be there. Also 2nd thing, Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through httpd.conf, please check if its enabled or not. Put a dummy line `-------` and hit any url if 500 internal error comes then it means your htaccess is enabled else not.

Comment: htaccess and mod_rewrite are anabled because some other rules - for another pages - works fine. About httpd.conf - is it accessable via cpanel or ... what? I'm afraid it is not possible in my case, because recently I tried to change something in `php.ini` and my host admin says - no, you cannot - tell us what to change - and wi will change that.

Comment: @provance, ok so you can't get OR check httpd.conf file? not sure for cpanel thing.

Comment: please see this - now, after changing all my links to absolute - there is no problem with my old code - with or without slash - it works

Comment: @provance, ok so with new code when you hit link http://localhost:80/video is working if not then please do let me know the error you are seeing on browser. Also my code have additional conditions which will help you to avoid unnecessary problems, so would like to request you to use these ones.

Comment: I'm not on localhost but on remote server directly - do you need to know my remote address ?

Comment: @provance, yeah it was just an example we use here, you can use your actual url and let me know with my rules how it goes. Sorry I am little confuse now :)

Comment: try here - `gpj.rs/clanovi/` - with or without last slash. It gives `404`. But now your seccond block of code - with get params - works fine. Don't be confused aboud `video` and `clanovi` - I said `video` - because it's just easear to understand for english speaking people.

Comment: @provance, ok sure, I have edited rules, could you please check my edited rules once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: yes, I'm sure it is LiteSpeed, not Apache. Please excuse me - you changed the order of some lines in your update and I didn't copied it correctly. Now I did - and everything works fine. Please excuse me. Only one question - is there any downside of having all links absolute ?

Comment: @provance, Glad to hear All is Well now. I am not an expert but relative paths having more downside compare to absolute paths :)

Comment: Oh, no, you're a heavenly expert. Proved so many times. Just hope you're paid enough for your knowledge. From my side I can only say - thanks - and thanks a lot.